# where({keypath:value, ...}) notation do not work

Tags: dexie

I'm using the official page example from [Table.where() documentation page](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.where().html):

```
db.friends.where({name: "David", age: 43}).first(friend => {
    console.log("Found David, 43: " + JSON.stringify(friend));
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error.stack || error);
});
```

It simply doesn't work. It can't find the "first" method.

It returns a `WhereClause`.

it should return a `Collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It applies to version 2.x only. Documentation mentions that but only in a comment. I updated the docs now to be more clear.

I can recommend to start using dexie@^2.0.0-beta.10 as it has been out for a while.

```
npm i dexie@next  --save
```